# Custom Event Box in dhtmlx-scheduler

Tags: reactjs, dhtmlx-scheduler

I am building a React application and using dhtmlx-scheduler for scheduling. On click of an event in the scheduler, I want to call a custom dialog box. I tried the link

https://docs.dhtmlx.com/scheduler/custom_details_form.html

but I am not able to do it. I tried looking at the source code, but in developer tools, I see a minified version of the file hence I can't add console statements

Also, I am using the free version of the scheduler.

Please help

Answer (score 0):

I tried the link, and now I am able to design a custom dialog box